# Firebase android error - java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/common/api/zzd.class

Tags: android, gradle, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi When I build my android app I get this error. I have recently started learning firebase and android. I would really appreciate if someone can help.
I have spend 3 hours on this error and still not able to solve it.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/common/api/zzd.class
```

Below is the app level build gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.com.date"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    }


}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
 compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  }
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Code - I am just trying to read data from fireapp db to my list view.
package app.com.date;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

 import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     private Button mSendData;
    private ListView mListView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("xxxxx");
        FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
            this, String.class, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            databaseReference){
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {
                TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                textView.setText(model);
            }
        };
        mListView.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);


    }

}
```

Comment: `firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0'` is the old Firebase. Why do you have it? https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android

Comment: Wherever you "started learning" from is using outdated sources. Read the actual up-to-date documetation

Comment: I am new and learning firebase. I tried to remove the client android.
Here is the updated list of file and error is still there compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1' compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'  compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1' compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.0' testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzacw.class

Comment: Your firebase-ui is outdated and conflicts with version 10.0.1

Comment: I tried using  com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1 but it didn't worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you use these

```
dependencies {
    // Support Libraries
    // compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1' // Not really needed
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'

    // Firebase UI + Database
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1'
}
```

Firebase UI includes the database

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

---

Or, apparently your app starts with

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.4'
```

But, it isn't unclear why using the latest version won't work.

Comment: have these 3 
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.0.1'

And error is still there
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/common/api/zza.class

Comment: If you have any JAR files in the libs folder related to google play services or firebase, delete them

Comment: i cleaned jars and the problem is still there.

Comment: And if you remove the Firebase dependency (and related code), does the app work?

Comment: I now have  compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1' and compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.4'

My app launches but closes immediately and i am not seeing any error, why i am not able to fetch data :(

Comment: The logcat should tell you why the app closes. Make sure Android Studio shows "connected devices"

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                  at app.com.date.MainActivity$1.populateView(MainActivity.java:31)
                                                                  at app.com.date.MainActivity$1.po

Comment: app.com.date E/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
                                                           java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                               at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                               at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)

Comment: can you please take a remote login to my computer via team viewer and help me out?

Comment: Sorry, can't do that. I'm not a personal tutor. Your code runs and we have fixed your initial error. NullPointerExeception is obviously that `findViewById` is returning the correct information, but given the wrong id. Hint: `android.R.id.text1` is not the same as `R.id.text1`...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure any of the library from google you use, should have same version number.

```
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'
```

In my case play services version was different so I make it same

```
    com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0
```